# Attempting to determine if a transformed range is empty

Tags: c++, range-v3

Attempting to build code which takes a vector, applies a view filter and then a transform, finally returning the last element if it exists:

```
int foo()
{
  std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 5, 3, 8, 9};
  auto r =
    v
    | view::filter([] (auto i) { return i % 2 == 0; })
    | view::transform([] (auto i) { return i * 2; });

  return r.empty() ? 0 : r.back();
}
```

Compiling this results in the following error:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int foo()':
test.cpp:14:18: error: no matching function for call to 'ranges::v3::transform_view<ran
ges::v3::remove_if_view<ranges::v3::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*
, std::vector<int> > >, ranges::v3::logical_negate_<foo()::<lambda(auto:1)> > >, foo()::<lambda(auto:2)> >::empty()'
   return r.empty() ? 0 : r.back();
                  ^
In file included from range-v3/include/range/v3/view_facade.hpp:21:0,
                 from range-v3/include/range/v3/core.hpp:21,
                 from range-v3/include/range/v3/all.hpp:17,
                 from test.cpp:1:
range-v3/include/range/v3/view_interface.hpp:88:28: note: candidate: template<in
t _concept_requires_87, typename std::enable_if<((_concept_requires_87 == 43) || ((ranges::v3::cardinality)-1 >= 0)), int>::type <anonymous
> > constexpr bool ranges::v3::view_interface<Derived, <anonymous> >::empty() const [with int _concept_requires_87 = _concept_requires_87;
typename std::enable_if<((_concept_requires_87 == 43) || (Cardinality >= 0)), int>::type <anonymous> = <enumerator>; Derived = ranges::v3::
iter_transform_view<ranges::v3::remove_if_view<ranges::v3::iterator_range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >, __gnu_cxx:
:__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> > >, ranges::v3::logical_negate_<foo()::<lambda(auto:1)> > >, ranges::v3::indirected<foo()::<lamb
da(auto:2)> > >; ranges::v3::cardinality Cardinality = (ranges::v3::cardinality)-1]
```

So, it looks like the transform_view is missing the Cardinality concept, regardless of the fact that it's operating on a transformed vector.  Is there an operator that can be applied to the range that would allow this code to work?  It seems odd that `empty()` requires Cardinality as it only has to validate whether there's *any* elements rather than provide the exact number of elements.

Comment: I think range does not have empty function, so the good way is to test if begin() == end() I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`view::filter` produced an `InputRange` in older versions of range-v3, which consequently doesn't provide `empty` or `back` (to avoid people writing bugs in which they call `begin` repeatedly on an input view). You need range-v3 0.3.6 or trunk, in which `view::filter` is bidirectional if the underlying range is bidirectional.